# Bitcoin core stopped sync'ing (without downloading all the data). How can I make it resume the synchronization?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoin-core, synchronization

I am extremely new to this concept but just decided to try. Unfortunately I did not do my homework before playing with my money.
I bought some coins and I sent them to my Bitcoin core wallet (that I had just installed, knowing nothing about the fact that it needed to sync first). I realized that since it wasn't synchronized I would need to wait until it finished downloading all of the data for me to have access to that money.

the problem is that my bitcoin core just stopped downloading data with the loading bar still in the middle and it is no longer synchronizing.

How can I make my bitcoin core complete to download all the data?

Comment: Are you running a recent version? Significant performance improvements have been made over time.

Comment: To properly answer this question, we would have needed to know what was in `debug.log`, and asked a number of other troubleshooting questions.  Now that's it's years old, that seems pointless, so I'm voting to close as "unclear" and get Community to stop bumping it.

Answer (score 0):

There are pretty much two stages. The first stage is to download (catch up) the whole blockchain that has 64.4 GB.

Once you have that the verification stage checks all payments ever made.

Both these things are pretty painful but once both are done you can backup your blockchain for example to external disk and you won't ever have to do it again.

Don't delete your wallet file.  **Backup your wallet.dat file.**

So delete everything, restart bitcoin, let it run for a few days and hope it doesn't get stuck.

Good luck.

Edit: do you have enough free disk space?

Edit2: don't delete the wallet

Comment: Note that stage 1 and stage 2 run in parallel. Downloading and verifying of already downloaded blocks. (That's a requirement for proper pruning.)

Comment: I've just edited your answer as there is no need to fear deleting wallet.dat

Comment: @Comodore: Yes there is. The asker has already bought Bitcoin and had them sent to his Bitcoin Core wallet.

Comment: I assumed the wallet.dat is something that gets backed up automaticaly + on will of user to secure his funds.

Comment: "don't delete the wallet" should be in bold and at the top :)